How can I define a Generator for a long Id if the field is in a @IdClass
This is the main class that is giving me problems.
@Entity
@Table(name = "api_channel_connection")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "API_CHANNEL_CONN_GEN",
    strategy = "native",
    parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "API_CHANNEL_CONN_SEQ")}
)
@IdClass(ApiChannelConnPk.class)
public class ApiChannelConn implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1704230312029411642L;

@Id
@Column(name="id", nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "API_CHANNEL_CONN_GEN")
private long id;

@Id
@Column(name = "api_channel_name", nullable = false)
private String apiChannelName;

@Column(name = "node", nullable = false)
private String node;

@Column(name = "url", nullable = false)
private String url;
}

Here is the ID class
public class ApiChannelConnPk implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -9009457097300195124L;

private long id;

private String apiChannelName;
}

My application needs to be able to connect to MariaDB or Oracle DB, In MariaDB the code sql looks like
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

But in Oracle we need to define how the ID will be increment so it looks like,
ID NUMBER(11,0) NOT NULL

CREATE SEQUENCE DATABASE.API_CHANNEL_CONN_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DATABASE.API_CHANNEL_CONN_TR
     BEFORE INSERT ON DATABASE.API_CHANNEL_CONNECTION FOR EACH ROW
     WHEN (NEW.ID IS NULL)
BEGIN
SELECT DATABASE.API_CHANNEL_CONN_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
END;

Right now I am testing using MariaDB, but I am getting an error because when it comes to the Spring @IdClass() annotation, I cannot define the generation type of my Id, From my understanding this wont be needed for MariaDB, but how can I ensure that the oracle database will increment if the field cannot take my custom generator.
Here is the stack trace
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set long field domain.ApiChannelConnPk.id to org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper$2
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.java:102)


The issue arises because @GeneratedValue cannot be used with composite keys defined using @IdClass. To resolve this, remove @GeneratedValue and manage the id field manually. For Oracle, implement a service to fetch the next sequence value using a native query (SELECT <sequence_name>.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL). Before persisting the entity, set the id field using this service. For MariaDB, the database will handle the auto-increment behavior automatically.

For the Oracle side, consider defining the id field as an identity column, and setting it to auto-generate (introduced in Oracle Database 12c).
This has the effect of populating the id field on the database side, without needing to define a database sequence:
id number generated always as identity primary key

This article also has some good information about using identity columns in Oracle Database: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1
This can give you a good alternative to sequences and triggers. Hope this helps!
